# How to get scrollbar in msstackedcolumn2d fusion chart

Tags: html, fusioncharts

I have been using fusion charts for many applications. Recently I used msstackedcolumn2d chart and I am trying to get horizontal scrollbar for my chart. Can anyone tell me how to get scrollbar in msstackedcolumn2d chart ?

```
FusionCharts.ready(function () {
    var revenueChart = new FusionCharts({
        type: 'msstackedcolumn2d',
        renderAt: 'chart-container',
        width: '550',
        height: '350',
        dataFormat: 'json',
        dataSource: {
  "chart": {
    "caption": "Request Report",
    "xaxisname": "Month",
    "yaxisname": "No. of Request",
    "paletteColors": "#0075c2,#45AFF5,#2C8A56,#1aaf5d,#50DE90",
    "bgColor": "#ffffff",
    "borderAlpha": "20",
    "showCanvasBorder": "0",
    "usePlotGradientColor": "0",
    "plotBorderAlpha": "10",
    "legendBorderAlpha": "0",
    "legendShadow": "0",
    "valueFontColor": "#ffffff",
    "showXAxisLine": "1",
    "showPercentValues": "1",
    "showPercentInToolTip": "0",
    "xAxisLineColor": "#999999",
    "divlineColor": "#999999",
    "divLineIsDashed": "1",
    "showAlternateHGridColor": "0",
    "subcaptionFontBold": "0",
    "subcaptionFontSize": "14"
  },
  "categories": [
    {
      "category": [
        {
          "label": "jan"
        },
        {
          "label": "feb"
        },
        {
          "label": "mar"
        },
        {
          "label": "apr"
        },
        {
          "label": "may"
        },
        {
          "label": "june"
        },
        {
          "label": "july"
        },
        {
          "label": "aug"
        },
        {
          "label": "sep"
        },
        {
          "label": "oct"
        },
        {
          "label": "nov"
        },
        {
          "label": "dec"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "dataset": [
    {
      "dataset": [
        {
          "seriesname": "Req_Total",
          "data": [
            {
              "value": "8000"
            },
            {
              "value": "600"
            },
            {
              "value": "100"
            },
            {
              "value": "400"
            },
            {
              "value": "200"
            },
            {
              "value": "200"
            },
            {
              "value": "100"
            },
            {
              "value": "2000"
            },
            {
              "value": "300"
            },
            {
              "value": "700"
            },
            {
              "value": "400"
            },
            {
              "value": "500"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "seriesname": "Req_Success",
          "data": [
            {
              "value": "600"
            },
            {
              "value": "500"
            },
            {
              "value": "200"
            },
            {
              "value": "300"
            },
            {
              "value": "100"
            },
            {
              "value": "8000"
            },
            {
              "value": "200"
            },
            {
              "value": "100"
            },
            {
              "value": "2000"
            },
            {
              "value": "200"
            },
            {
              "value": "900"
            },
            {
              "value": "400"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "seriesname": "Req_Fail",
          "data": [
            {
              "value": "500"
            },
            {
              "value": "400"
            },
            {
              "value": "8000"
            },
            {
              "value": "2000"
            },
            {
              "value": "200"
            },
            {
              "value": "600"
            },
            {
              "value": "2000"
            },
            {
              "value": "200"
            },
            {
              "value": "100"
            },
            {
              "value": "300"
            },
            {
              "value": "1000"
            },
            {
              "value": "300"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "dataset": [
        {
          "seriesname": "Status",
          "data": [
            {
              "value": "500"
            },
            {
              "value": "400"
            },
            {
              "value": "8000"
            },
            {
              "value": "2000"
            },
            {
              "value": "200"
            },
            {
              "value": "600"
            },
            {
              "value": "10000"
            },
            {
              "value": "5000"
            },
            {
              "value": "100"
            },
            {
              "value": "200"
            },
            {
              "value": "100"
            },
            {
              "value": "300"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "dataset": [
        {
          "seriesname": "Downloaded",
          "data": [
            {
              "value": "600"
            },
            {
              "value": "500"
            },
            {
              "value": "200"
            },
            {
              "value": "300"
            },
            {
              "value": "100"
            },
            {
              "value": "8000"
            },
            {
              "value": "5000"
            },
            {
              "value": "100"
            },
            {
              "value": "2000"
            },
            {
              "value": "100"
            },
            {
              "value": "200"
            },
            {
              "value": "400"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
    });

    revenueChart.render();
});
```

I have also created [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sghxojj9/2/)

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that is not possible in FusionCharts as of now,as scroll charts are different set of charts, where multi series stacked column is presently not there,however if you can share the use case scenario, I can suggest you with a suitable chart type

Comment: My use case is to have month labels starting from jan to dec. And series having req_total,req_success,req_failure,status,downloaded. I am trying to find a chart where I can combine req_total,req_success,req_failure

Comment: so why you need a scroll bar? I am referring to your fiddle here- http://jsfiddle.net/sghxojj9/2/

Comment: The numbers are not clearly visible in it. Moreover the bar width also I want to increase